# Datastore Query filtering on list

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Select all records, ID which is not in the list

How to make like :

```
query = Story.all()

query.filter('ID **NOT IN** =', [100,200,..,..])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to do this efficiently in App Engine. You should simply select everything without that filter, and filter out any matching entities in your code.

Answer (score 2):

This is now supported via GQL query

> The 'IN' and '!=' operators in the Python runtime are actually
>   implemented in the SDK and translate to multiple queries 'under the
>   hood'.
>
> For example, the query "SELECT * FROM People WHERE name IN ('Bob',
>   'Jane')" gets translated into two queries, equivalent to running
>   "SELECT * FROM People WHERE name = 'Bob'" and "SELECT * FROM People
>   WHERE name = 'Jane'" and merging the results. Combining multiple
>   disjunctions multiplies the number of queries needed, so the query
>   "SELECT * FROM People WHERE name IN ('Bob', 'Jane') AND age != 25"
>   generates a total of four queries, for each of the possible conditions
>   (age less than or greater than 25, and name is 'Bob' or 'Jane'), then
>   merges them together into a single result set.

source: [appengine blog](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2009/06/10-things-you-probably-didnt-know-about.html)

Comment: Interesting note: The blog you mention above was written by the same person who wrote the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, so I'm not sure if the `ID` is a non-key property. But in order to answer this:

```py
query = Story.all()
query.filter('ID **NOT IN** =', [100,200,..,..])
```

...With [ndb](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/) models, you can definitely query for items that are in a list. For example, see the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries#neq_and_in) for `IN` and `!=`. Here's how to filter as the OP requested:

```py
query = Story.filter(Story.id.IN([100,200,..,..])
```

We can even query for items that in a list of repeated keys:

```py
def all(user_id):
    # See if my user_id is associated with any Group.
    groups_belonged_to = Group.query().filter(user_id == Group.members)
    print [group.to_dict() for group in belong_to]
```

**Some caveats:**

There's docs out there that mention that in order to perform these types of queries, Datastore performs multiple queries behind the scenes, which (1) might take a while to execute, (2) take longer if you searching in repeated properties, and (3) will up your costs with more operations.